# I have 2 forms and I want to run with form1 but it start with form2 Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 forms and I want to run with form1 but it start with form2 (Visual Basic)

Comment: you really need to tell us more.

Answer (score 4):

Right click your project, click properties, select the Application tab, Change Startup Object from Form1 to Form2.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow step-by-step as the below image
[image]